# Error on Document conversion of DOCX doc with Quick Parts

Tags: error, document-converter, development, 2007

I started using the document conversion feature with MOSS 2007 and Word 2007.
The process seems to work fine with DOCX documents.

So I tried adding quick parts metadata to the docs, and no luck.
Can someone please shed some light on it?

I believe the first error was
LocationSelector.ascx: empty location ID on postback
D:\Program Files\Microsoft Office Servers\12.0\Bin\HtmlTrLauncher\output.html file DOESN'T exist.  Deleting path, returning, and blocklisting
error code CE_OTHER_BLOCKLIST from the document conversions framework in the callback handler

then i get this monster

During the conversion of contents for page 'Pages/AEX-OP-1-1 initial.aspx', the following warnings were encountered: 'An internal converter error occured. Further information may be available in the log files that are accessible to your system administrator.System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Expression must evaluate to a node-set.     at System.Xml.Xsl.Runtime.XsltConvert.EnsureNodeSet(IList`1 listItems)     at <xsl:template match="w:tc">(XmlQueryRuntime {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}runtime, XPathNavigator {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}current, Double {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}position, Double {urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt-debug}last, IList`1 sTblStyleName, IList`1 prsPAccum, IList`1 prsP, IList`1 prsR, IList`1 cellspacing, IList`1 cellpadding.default, IList`1 cellpadding.custom, IList`1 bdr.top, IList`1 bdr.left, IList`1 bdr.bottom, IList`1 bdr.right, IList`1 bdr.insideV, IList`1 bdr.insideH, IList`1 thisRow, IList`1 lastRow, String cnfRow, IList`1 b.bidivisual)     at

Comment: The error seems to be cut short? Could you edit your post with the whole trace?